# iOS Adding Dynamic Values to Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, ios7

I want to add dynamic values of `UIImage` in array which initialised in the for loop,  So I created a `NSMutableArray` to set object first in for loop and later tried to retrieve values from that. 
Please can you look where I am going wrong and what should be best approch while adding the dynamic values.

```
NSMutableDictionary * dic= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *cImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    NSString * imageKey= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i",i+1];              

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [[results objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:imageKey]]];
    UIImage *imageOne = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [dic setObject:imageOne forKey:imageKey];

}

for (NSString *key in dic) {
    NSString *sprite = [dic objectForKey:key];
    //adding below to the array
    [cImages addObject:sprite];             
}
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What doesn't work as you expect it to?

Comment: Aren't you trying to get an NSString out of dic when it should be a UIImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with just adding UIImage's to the mutable array?

```
NSMutableArray *cImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    NSString *imageKey= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i", i+1];
    UIImage *imageToAdd = [UIImage imageNamed:imageKey];
    [cImages addObject:imageToAdd];
}

// Using the images
for (UIImage *image in cImages)
{
    // Do whatever u want with each image.
}
```

If you really need to use a dictionary to access the UIImage's by the names "image1, image2" etc you can do this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    NSString *imageKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i", i+1];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfImageFile.png"];
    [dict setObject:image forKey:imageKey];
}

// Now you can access the UIImage values by their names (image1,image2,image3,image4,image5)
UIImage *imageToUse = [dict valueForKey:@"image1"];
```

(haven't test these, but it's fairly standard).